# Don’t Get Fired - what’s the point of almost all the upgrades when work comes in so slowly?

Tags: dont-get-fired

All of the “working” and “health” skill upgrades help you work faster, but after a few investments in working, you easily go through all the work available and spend half the time just waiting.

So, what’s the point of even upgrading further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can easily handle the workload without the later ugrades, you can get a lot of extra work when the president shows up. You can then work through the backlog  once he leaves.

At a certain rank, you can motivate your team (anyone lower than you) to work faster. This costs health- more health means you can get faster xp and money this way.